# Search for similar names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, compare

I want to help my Boss so I figured I'll ask you lot.

We have a database for users containing among many things, name, email, address, phone, etc...

The issue with many users is that they are often unable to write their name or email address correctly and thus, they register 3 times with different email addresses, but with 1 or 2 letter differences due to them making TYPO errors.

I would like to have a query that can show us similar names or email addresses that are present in the database. Is there an easy way to do it? Was experimenting with SOUNDS LIKE, but that does not return anything. :/

Comment: Which server side language are you going to use? Or do you want to create a function in MySQL?

Comment: Just a query for one time usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm. In short "the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other". Thus, the lower the distance (say < 4) the strings are similar.

There's an MySQL implementation of a function [here](https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/).

If you want to take all records then do the "math" using JavaScript you can use this code: (From [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/levenshtein-distance-in-javascript))

```js
const str1 = 'hitting';
const str2 = 'kitten';
const levenshteinDistance = (str1 = '', str2 = '') => {
  const track = Array(str2.length + 1).fill(null).map(() =>
    Array(str1.length + 1).fill(null));
  for (let i = 0; i <= str1.length; i += 1) {
    track[0][i] = i;
  }
  for (let j = 0; j <= str2.length; j += 1) {
    track[j][0] = j;
  }
  for (let j = 1; j <= str2.length; j += 1) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= str1.length; i += 1) {
      const indicator = str1[i - 1] === str2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1;
      track[j][i] = Math.min(
        track[j][i - 1] + 1, // deletion
        track[j - 1][i] + 1, // insertion
        track[j - 1][i - 1] + indicator, // substitution
      );
    }
  }
  return track[str2.length][str1.length];
};
console.log(levenshteinDistance(str1, str2));
```

Comment: OK, but how to I implement this is a query only if possible? I don't want to use any programing languages like PHP, JS or other. Just a  query in DBeaver.

Comment: Also, as far as I can see, it compares records only to strings I input and not other values in the DB.